# Gitlab-CI ends with error message about events list

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Since a few days some of my failed pipelines on a private Gitlab end with this odd error message:

> ERROR: Error retrieving events list: events is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:runner1-gitlab-runner" cannot
> list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace
> "gitlab-runner"

I couldn't find any information about this error. Are the runners out of date or incompatible with the Gitlab version? Is something configured wrong?